# IFrame doesn't shrink on IPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

Open layout (https://codepen.io/vladislavlobakh/project/editor/ZBQyPM) on IPad 6th, or Pro (IOS 11-12).

The layout is braking on IPads, because iframe stretches and I can't apply width style for it.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnHrA.png

```
<div class="content">
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<iframe class="iframe" src="content.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

it's working correctly on some other tablets like Nexus 7 and chrome emulators of IPad.

https://codepen.io/vladislavlobakh/project/editor/ZBQyPM

ER: Iframe should shrink and layout is presented fully.

AR: It doesn't

Comment: any suggestions on how to solve the problem?